# Getting the nearest summation of an auto-incremented integer

Tags: mysql, math

I have an SQL table that auto-increments each row. The row has position data of a planet to be placed onto a ring. The 1st ring will have one planet, the 2nd will have two, and so on.

As example, the 1st planet will be on the 1st ring, planets 2-3 will be on the 2nd, planets 4-6 on the 3rd, 7-10 on the 4th, and so on. What formula can I use to find the nearest summation for the unique integer like so?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't ask me why but the rounded, integer square root of the planet number will give you the result you are looking for. 0 has a square root of 0, 1&2 have square roots of 1 etc. Each square has 2 more roots than the preceding value - something I came across figuring out fast integer square roots on the 6502 processor.

Comment: Actually, it's been a while but it might be 1,3,5 etc so you might have to adjust the result.